# Combi boiler chemical replacement

Tags: plumbing, chemicals

I have a combi boiler (less than 2 years old, with plumbing that may be 25 years old) and I'm doing some work which will require a full drain of the heating system.

I think I'm going to need some cleaner and some inhibitor, but I'm wondering - can I just add both to the newly-topped up system, or is there a process I'll need to follow?

I am looking at Sentinel [X100 inhibitor](https://www.toolstation.com/sentinel-x100-system-inhibitor/p68383) and [X400 cleaner](https://www.toolstation.com/sentinel-x400-sludge-remover/p28178)

Comment: I wouldn't use a cleaner unless there was a specific problem ( If it ain't broke , don't fix it.), There is no information on the site : Possibly  they are sulfamic acid , used to clean water systems without damage to steel ( hopefully).

Comment: Thanks. I decided to swap the cleaner for extra inhibitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to drain the system and after using the cleaner, so put that in (and run the system a bit) before you start your maintennce.  the inhibitor goes in with the new water when your maintenance is done.